UART Write Failing in the first time/Intermittently on Zynq UltraScale+ (Kernel 5.15.167-Xilinx-v2022.2)
I am developing serial communication on a Xilinx Zynq UltraScale+ MPSoC using the xilinx_uartps driver with kernel version 5.15.167-xilinx-v2022.2. in application level. While the UART read functionality works as expected, I am experiencing a recurring issue with the write operation:
The first write fails or does not transmit the expected payload after a period of inactivity (around 3 minutes).
Subsequent writes work fine, but the issue reoccurs after another idle period.
Below is the initialization function,
INT32S HWUart::HwInit(){
INT32S RetVal = 0;

struct termios TermOptions;

INT32S UartDeviceFileDescriptor = pDriver->GetDeviceFileDescriptor();

if (::isatty(UartDeviceFileDescriptor) != 1)
{
throw MSG("Invalid file descriptor");
}

if ( ::tcgetattr(UartDeviceFileDescriptor, &TermOptions) < 0)
{
  throw MSG("Unable to get terminal options");
}
// blocking read is configured
::cfmakeraw(&TermOptions);
TermOptions.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
TermOptions.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

speed_t BAUDRATE = __GetBaudRateinSpeed_t();

// Configure input speed
if ( ::cfsetispeed(&TermOptions, BAUDRATE) < 0)
{
  throw MSG("Unable to set input speed");
}

// Configure output speed
if ( ::cfsetospeed(&TermOptions, BAUDRATE) < 0)
{
  throw MSG("Unable to set output speed");
}

//clear all the control bit
TermOptions.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;

//Configure Data Bit
__SetDataBit(&TermOptions);

//Configure Parity Bit
__SetParityBit(&TermOptions);

//Configure Stop Bit
__SetStopBit(&TermOptions);


if( ::tcsetattr(UartDeviceFileDescriptor, TCSANOW, &TermOptions) < 0)
{
throw MSG("Unable to set terminal options");
}

// flushes both data received but not read, and data written but not transmitted
if ( ::tcflush(UartDeviceFileDescriptor, TCIOFLUSH) < 0)
{
  throw MSG("Unable to flush terminal");
}
//Wait for stabilising control line
TXL_CMLIB::SysTimeInterface::DelayMs(60U);

return RetVal;
}

WriteMessage function:
INT32S HWUart::WriteMessage(const INT8U* buf, INT32U size)
{
  INT32U RetVal = 0;
  
  INT32S UartDeviceFileDescriptor = GetDriver()->GetDeviceFileDescriptor();

  if (size >= BUFFER_LEN)
  {
    throw MSG("LEMO Serial transmission buffer can send upto 248 bytes");
  }
  
  RetVal = ::write(UartDeviceFileDescriptor, buf, size);
  
  if (RetVal < size)
  {
    throw MSG("Unable to send Lemo reply");
  }
  
  return RetVal;
}

i also tried Sent dummy writes before actual data (worked but not allowed by design). Closed and reopened the file descriptor before each write(not working). Reapplied UART configurations using tcsetattr() before each write(not working).
Observations:
The /sys/class/tty/ttyPS0/device/power/runtime_status remains "active."
The autosuspend_delay_ms was set to 3000 (default), and I tried disabling it by setting it to -1 and changing control to on, but this did not resolve the issue.
Using tcdrain(), tcflush(), and toggling RTS/CTS control did not help.
No relevant logs appear in dmesg. please suggest your input,

"The first write fails or does not transmit the expected payload ..." - That's an ambiguous description. A write() return code that is less than the request size needs more analysis, e.g. you fail to check for an actual error! The code you posted is not sufficient; you also need to show how you open the serial terminal. Your termios configuration is incomplete; you leave the config for HW flow control and modem control lines completely up to chance. BTW you may be using the xilinx_uartps driver, but your application program accesses a serial terminal (or tty) rather than a UART.

An Ambiguous description - I meant first write completes without returning an error, but the transmitted data does not match the expected payload. return code is size of the what i transmitted. fd is opened as below " if (m_deviceFilePath == NULL){ throw MSG("ERROR");} if (!IsOpened()) { m_deviceFileDescriptor = ::open(m_deviceFilePath, O_RDWR); if (m_deviceFileDescriptor < 0){throw MSG("Failed to open the file device");}}" I tried configuration for HW flow control and Modem control lines also, It doesn't resolve the issue. but serial1 has only compatible in dts.I will more to makesure on tty.
